# How to aggregate on elasticsearch field of type string that includes a slash (/)

Tags: elasticsearch

How to aggregate on field of type string which has a format `11/03/2015` i.e. treat string as date without re-indexing? For example, Consider the mapping for an Elasticsearch `index:sport`, `type:athlete`:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/sports/" -d'
{
  "mappings": {
     "athlete": {
        "properties": {
           "birthdate": {
           "type": "string"    
           },
            "name": {
            "type": "string"
           },
            "score": {
            "type": "integer"
           },
            "sport": {
            "type": "string"
           }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Aggregating on `birthdate` appears to separate field using the `/` and therefore aggregates on `11/03/2015` as `11`, `03`, `2015` rather than taking as a whole and aggregating on it. How to fix this? :

```
"buckets": [
        {
           "key": "2015",
           "doc_count": 24
        },
        {
           "key": "11",
           "doc_count": 21
        },
        {
           "key": "03",
           "doc_count": 3
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES mapping defaults to analyzer. Changing the index to `not_analyzed` fixed the problem:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/sports/" -d'
{
 "mappings": {
    "athlete": {
      "properties": {
        "birthdate": {
          "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"    
            },
        "name": {
        "type": "string"
       },
        "score": {
        "type": "integer"
       },
        "sport": {
        "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping for birthday should not be string type. Instead it should be "date". You can also specify format with the mapping if you want. This link will help you.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html#date