# How to aggregate on elasticsearch field of type string which includes a slash (/)

Tags: elasticsearch

How to aggregate on field of type string which has a format /search/suggest.I'm searching with php's elasticsearch client. i want to group the result by the field named uri.
but the result will be group by each word split by slash.Such as

```
 [buckets] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => search
                                [doc_count] => 4
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => suggest
                                [doc_count] => 4
                            )

                    )
```

I have searched some questions such as [How to aggregate on elasticsearch field of type string that includes a slash (/)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501832/how-to-aggregate-on-elasticsearch-field-of-type-string-that-includes-a-slash)

but in my es version ,I can't changing the index to not_analyzed.
the error reason is

> "reason":"Failed to parse value [not_analyzed] as only [true] or [false]

then I searched https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/761

but I also can't change the fieldtype to keyword.

Then I found this [Migrate field type from text to keyword on ElasticsearchEDIT:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925217/migrate-field-type-from-text-to-keyword-on-elasticsearchedit)

is there any other solutions?  I don't know how to create a new index.It's my workmate's work. But i don't know which one it is. So is there any other solutions without create a new index.
Thanks

Comment: the cleanest way to do it is: create a new index with the correct mapping, the ones you had been suggested, use the `reindex` api to "copy/paste" all the data from source to the new destination, run the queries, test in the new index.